# secure data exchange between mobile and .net platforms

Tags: .net, iphone, android, blackberry, nokia

We are developing a product with .net web services and Android, iPhone, BlackBerry, Nokia, and Windows Mobile clients.  The mobile apps are exchanging data with the server.  For that exchange, I need to provide secure communication for the data.  How do we do encryption and decryption between these different languages?

Comment: if i develop aes encyption in c or c++.is it possible to use this native code in all platforms

Comment: Edited to remove request for code and remove 'urgent'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use an encrypted transport e.g. https.

Using https has lots of advantages:

- The encryption is all sorted for you, you just use the system services provided.
- It's easy to switch between http and https for debugging reasons.
- You don't get any problems for devices where you need to sign the application for a store, e.g. iPhone, if you include encryption in your application (other than transport encryption like https) you have to jump through more hoops and have a lot longer wait to get it into the appstore.